# PyCharm Professional 2020.2 - missing "Run Anything" option?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I recently discovered the double CTRL tap for "Run Anything" on IntelliJ for "Run Anything". I tried to do the same on PyCharm Professional, but nothing came up. Upon looking at the key mappings, "Run Anything" doesn't even exist.

I use OSX. I had a friend check on Ubuntu too and it was also missing for him.

Anyone happen to know how to get that functionality into PyCharm?

Comment: 1) Go to `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Keymap` and type `anything` in the local search box -- do you see "Run Anything" action under "Other" node? 2) `Ctrl` x2 does not work for you, will it show up if you assign custom shortcut for that action?

Comment: @LazyOne https://i.imgur.com/HvBaoVX.png it's not present.

Comment: Apparently it's not in PyCharm Pro yet. E.g. recent [PY-43980](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-43980) marked as duplicate of [PY-31773](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31773) -- watch this ticket for updates.